# How do i check a Radiobutton list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, radiobuttonlist

How do I check a radio button?? Here is the radio button list:

```
<div class="md-radio-list">
  <label class="md-radio" id="@ch.AnswerId">
    <input name="@ch.QuestionId" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="@id" type="radio">
    <span></span>
    <label for="@id">
      <span class="inc"></span>
      <span class="check"></span>
      <span class="box"></span> @ch.AnswerText
    </label>
  </label>
</div>
```

Here the radio buttons are dynamic, They will bind to the radio button list.

I have tried :

```
  <input name="@ch.QuestionId" checked="checked" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="@id" type="radio">
```

But it's not working.

Comment: we'd need to see how or where you defined `handlesCick`

Comment: without handleclick how do i check

Comment: *"it's not working"* is not a proper problem statement. You also haven't provided all the relevant code as per [mcve]

Comment: if i click onclick="true" is it working??

Comment: can anyone tell me without javascript simple way to check just like checked="checked"

Comment: you would need some server side logic to output the checked property based on your model

Comment: you just tell me how do i checked here

Comment: what is the server side logic need to implement

Answer (score 2):

Use below to check without any event (click)

```
document.getElementById("@id").checked=true
```

Snippet

```js
document.getElementById("@id").checked = true
```

```html
<div class="md-radio-list">
  <label class="md-radio" id="@ch.AnswerId">

<input name="@ch.QuestionId" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="@id" type="radio">
<span></span>
 <label for="@id">
<span class="inc"></span>
<span class="box"></span>
 @ch.AnswerText</label>
  </label>
</div>
```

HTML Solution:

Simply add   `checked` attribute in your element

```
<input name="@ch.QuestionId" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="@id" type="radio"  checked>
```

Comment: <input name="@ch.QuestionId" onclick="handlesClick(this);" id="@id" type="radio"> how do i check without javascript

Comment: because i need a conditions where some radio buttons are checked

Comment: Include in your question that you don't want a javascript approach and I'll retract my response

Comment: without javascript simple way to check just like checked="checked" ??

Comment: i think may be onclick something may work..can you tell me just like...when page load i want the check box selected

Answer (score 0):

$('input[type="radio"]').attr("checked", true); //this will check all radio buttons

$('#id').attr("checked", true); //this will check specific radio